# suspended Ubuntu One account

Tags: login

how do I re-enable a suspended Ubuntu One account. Trying to log in with my credentials, server responds that account has been suspended and call login support for re-enabling. Login support agent called responds to come here.

Comment: Does https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSO/FAQs help you?

Comment: Did you try emailing them? I would imagine such support people prefer an email: isd-support@canonical.com